# What are some of the parameters that should be kept in mind while working on handwriting matching project?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, handwriting

I am currently working on a project on Handwriting Matching algorithm where I am given some test data (images with text handwritten in English Language ) . I have to determine by matching this data from the training data that for each test data , which person from the training set has most probable similar writing . I searched internet for papers related to this but I found only papers based on text extraction in which we have to determine what is written rather than determine who has written .
 I would be very helpful if I can get some insights on it and also some references or journals or papers so that I can work on an evolutionary algorithm rather than doing everything from scratch. It would be very useful If I can also get the links for paid papers/journals .

Comment: A quick search turned up that you're looking for writer identification. Scholar yields papers with quite a high reference count: [Automatic signature verification and writer identification — the state of the art](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031320389900599). I never did this myself, so you'll have to see through it yourself and come back with more specific questions

Answer (score 0):

In the last years, [Kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com/) hosted contests with the goal of identifying a writer. The contests were based on Arabic alphabet but I guess you could apply similar techniques to English letters.
You will have to dig the forums and results from these contests to actually find links to helpful ideas/papers.

[ICDAR 2011 - Arabic Writer Identification](http://www.kaggle.com/c/wic2011)

[ICFHR 2012 - Arabic Writer Identification](http://www.kaggle.com/c/awic2012)